# Dropdown list from MS-SQL and second value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have found this code and I slightly re-writte it. I want that when I select order value from dropdown list, is showing customer in text below.
I have to say, that I have very little VB programming experience, so I'm stuck here.

Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="True" Strict="True"  %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Odbc" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>

<font face="calibri">
<script runat="server">
Dim connStr As String = "server=MSSQLEXP;database=ppwin1;Uid=sa_ro;pwd=sa_ro"

Sub Userlist_Init(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs)
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
   conn.Open()
   Dim sql_user As String
   Dim cmd_user As Sqlcommand
    sql_User = "SELECT DISTINCT order, customer FROM dbo.T_CUSTOMER ORDER BY order ASC"
cmd_user = New Sqlcommand (sql_user, conn)
finduser.Datasource=cmd_user.ExecuteReader()
  finduser.datatextfield = "customer"
  finduser.databind()
conn.Close()
End Sub

Sub Finduser_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
txtuser.text = finduser.selecteditem.text
End sub

</script>
<html><head><title>Dropdown list from MS SQL DB</title></head>
<body><h1>Dropdown list from MS SQL DB</h1>
<br>
<form runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="finduser" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="Finduser_SelectedIndexChanged" OnInit="userlist_Init">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label id="txtuser" runat="server" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Rok

Comment: what's the problem..? please state your problem clearly so others might have more chance in helping you..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
finduser.Datasource = cmd_user.ExecuteReader()
finduser.datatextfield = "customer"
finduser.databind()
```

Did you tried this?

```
Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd_user.ExecuteReader
finduser.Items.Clear()
While dr.Read() 
   finduser.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr("customer"),dr("order"))
End While
```

OR

```
Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
dr = cmd_user.ExecuteReader
Dim myData as New DataTable
If dr.HasRows Then
    myData.Load(dr)
End If

ddldept.datasource = myData
ddldept.DataTextField = "customer"
ddldept.DataValueField = "order"
ddldept.DataBind()
```

Comment: Hi.

Thanks for your answer. I tried your 2nd version, but I get an error:
Compiler Error Message: BC30367: Class 'System.Data.DataTable' cannot be indexed because it has no default property.

Comment: I have made suggested changes, but I still get an error: Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.   Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'selectedtext' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'.
Line 32: txtuser.text = ddldept.selectedtext

Comment: There is no such property named "SelectedText" in a dropdownlist because of which you are getting this error. Your code of "txtuser.text = finduser.selecteditem.text" should work for the second part of my answer. If you are using my first part you might need to typecast "finduser.selecteditem" to "ListItem" and get "Text" property of it.